# How to draw shapes like circles, oval, ractangles dynamically in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, core-graphics

I have a UICollectionView of showing shapes like circles, oval, ractangles. So when I clicked on Cell I need to draw same shape on UIView and after I need to move and resize that view which was drawn by clicking in Cell. How it can achieve in iOS ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is good, but too brorad to answer

Comment: Got through [this](https://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/) and [this](https://mlsdev.com/blog/23-building-and-animating-user-interfaces-with-shapes-on-ios) blogs.

Comment: You need to read CoreGraphics :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use a UICollectionView, your reusable cell will have the "layer" to draw on.

What to do?

**1.** Create a `UIView` subclass and place it inside your reusable cell.

**2.** Override `drawRect(_:)` method, you'll do all the drawing inside.

**3.** Add your `shape/line drawing code` to drawRect method.

For example use `UIBezierPath` class for lines, arcs etc. You'll be able to create all sorts of shapes.

You should read the CoreGraphics API Ref:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics

also learn about `Layers`, `Contexts` and `drawRect:`

A very basic example of a `circle`:

```
class CircleView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return
        }
        context.addEllipse(in: rect)
        context.setFillColor(.red.cgColor)
        context.fillPath()
    }
}
```

and drawing lines (rects, stars etc.) with UIBezier paths:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
      var path = UIBezierPath()
      path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:<point x>, y:<point y>))
      path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:<next point x>, y:<next point y>))
      point.closePath()

      UIColor.redColor().set()
      point.stroke()
      point.fill()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

study about bezier path. It is possible with this. hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAShapeLayer. eg. Draw a circle.

```
shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.frame = aFrame;
UIBezierPath *spath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerPoint radius:12 startAngle:0 endAngle:(2 * M_PI) clockwise:YES];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:71/255.0 green:157/255.0 blue:252/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
shapeLayer.path = spath.CGPath;
shapeLayer.strokeStart = 0;
shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0;
shapeLayer.fillColor = nil;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2;
[self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

I hope it help you

Comment: are you seen this `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 0):

You can use layer's properties:

- cornerRadius
- borderWidth
- borderColor